# I cannot remove a workspace form P4V because its relative folder deleted in windows file explorer

Tags: perforce, workspace, p4v

I was setting up a small server to allow my friends to access Unreal Engine documents. I am completely new to this. I accidentally made an extra folder. I didn't notice I didn't need it at the time and made it a workspace. Then I realized and deleted it in the window file explorer. However, as I figured out it did not remove it from P4V.
Now, when I try to delete the workspace in P4V, I get the error message:

> "Client 'UE4Workspace1' has files opened. To delete the client, revert any opened files and delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client."

I do not know how to use `-f`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you have checked out some files in the workspace which you were trying to delete.

So to fix the problem:

1 switch to the workspace you want to delete.

2 revert these files in your pending change list (Or possibly in other changelist in that workspace)

3 delete any numbered changelists in that workspace.

4 switch to other workspace(this step is possibly optional)

5 delete the problemetic workspace in p4v.

I guess P4 maintains status of every workspace in the server. And to avoid mis-deleting local edited files, they will prevent users from deleting workspaces if the workspaces still have pending files.

Comment: Dude, thanks so much. It worked perfectly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct rights, you can from a command line, while being logged in the server,

```
p4 client -d -f <workspace_name>
```

-d : means delete

-f : means force

A client or a workspace in Perforce speak is the same thing. (I am not quite sure why there are two terms for the same thing.)

Full reference : https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html